# Scala way to add to List if not null

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Scala newbie here...

Doing below on address java object with getStLine*() methods...
yields a List with empty strings for the empty strings returned.
whats the Scala way to cleanly not add empty strings to a list.

```
val streets = List[String](addr.getStLine1, addr.getStLine2, addr.getStLine3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're explicitely adding strings to list, I don't think you'd be able to easily avoid adding empty strings without custom derived list implementation. On the other hand you can easily filter out empty strings after the fact.

```
scala> val z = List("one", "", "three")
z: List[java.lang.String] = List(one, "", three)

scala> z.filter(p=> p!=null && !p.equals(""))
res2: List[java.lang.String] = List(one, three)
```

Comment: By the way [in Scala you usually compare strings with `==` not like in Java](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-compare-strings-with-equal-operator-method-not-equals).

Comment: Yes, I do like the looks of this:     streets.filterNot(s => s == null || s == "" )

Comment: More idomatic : `z.filter(!_.isEmpty)`

Comment: @n1r3 that'll throw `null pointer`, isEmpty checks for 0 length, not nulls

Comment: the question is "cleanly not add empty strings", I didn't see anything about `null` in the question.

Comment: To avoid `null pointer exception`'s, perhaps you should modify your `getStLine-x` methods to return an `Option[String]`, and then do: `streets.flatten`. Example: `scala> List[Option[Int]](Some(1), None).flatten
res2: List[Int] = List(1)`